# structured normalization of a column of structured reference table?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a Table (i.e., a structured reference table) named `table1`, where columns have headers (but rows do not).  I want to produce a new column that is a normalization of an existing column (say, `c1`).  By "normalization" I just mean, in this case, that each element of the column is divided by the first element of the column.  Is there a structured way to do this?  (Note that Excel does not allow mixing structured and ordinary and references, so `table1[2,c1]` is not possible.  Even if it where possible, it would not be ideal, since the `2` would not be an offset from the table location.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mix references like so:

```
=[@alpha]/$A$2
```

However, if you're dedicated to this and the first row really is the one you want to use, you can use `INDEX` to get it.

```
=[@alpha]/INDEX([alpha],1)
```

Comment: Yes, the latter is pretty good.  I don't think the `@` is necessary, since I'm extending the same table,  Using `INDEX` is good.  I suppose more structure could be added by using `MATCH` to pick a unique identifier of the first row, but simply indexing meets my needs.